# Export API from Apache Wink

Tags: jax-rs, apache-wink

It looks like Apache Wink may be winding down and I'm thinking about porting a project that uses it to a new platform.

Is there a way to programmatically export the API served by my Apache Wink server?  I don't care about the format, if I have to manually read through it, I can.  I just don't want to manually hunt through all of the .java files looking at annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have seen has Wink no out of the box WADL implementation. To get WADL for your API try this solution from IBM https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxrs_wadl_serving.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Apache Wink seems to be on the decline. In the end we transitioned to Apache Jersey, which was relatively straightforward because it also uses JAX-RS annotations. Jersey allows you to generate WADL with one line. I'm glad to see there is some option for Wink, though.